# Java Packet Sniffer

Tags: java, tomcat, packet-sniffers

I want to create a packet sniffer program with which I can read all the data that my tomcat server receives. So I tried to use a simple server socket program but since the port (8080) is already used by tomcat I failed. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We sure can. Just pop on over to [wewritecodeforyou.com](http://static3.depositphotos.com/1005979/207/i/450/dep_2076346-Do-it-Yourself---Orange-Button.jpg).

Comment: http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/ does something like this..

Comment: If it is only for relatively short debugging sessions, you can use wireshark.

Answer (score 3):

I am not answering how you can write a sniffer but still wondering why do you want to do it when tomcat provides an option to dump the complete http requests. It may help you save a lot of time without actually writing any code and simply using the tomcat functionality. Read this

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve

Just configure tomcat by adding this to the end of your `server.xml` config under the tag "Host".

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it as a proxy as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) does.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`javax.servlet.Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). You can intercept every request, log it, then pass the request on.